# What does the star (*) operator with a number mean?

Tags: python

I been reading [What does the Star operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python), but I can't understand how the numbers come in. Could you explain to me the next expression:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

It's taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) v3.5

Comment: Read up on [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: It's the power operator. `x**2` means *`x` squared*, while `x**3` means *`x` to the third power*. Some languages use `^` instead (e.g. `x^2` for `x` squared) but in Python `^` is the XOR bit operator.  It's **completely** unreleated to the use of `**` or `*` in `f(**arguments)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `x` raised to the power 2.

Expanded out, the list comprehension has the meaning:

```
 x_2 = []
 for x in range(0,10):
    x_2.append(x**2)  # Take x to the power 2
```

Comment: I should of guess it, lols

Answer (score 1):

```
* # is the multiplication operator expression:

** # power operator so 3**2 = 9
```

Below is a list comprehension:

```
[f(x) for x in iterator]
```

so it creates a list with `f(x)`'s for each `x` as returned by the `iterator`

In this case f(x) = raising to the power of 2

range(10) are the numbers 0-->9

so for each number it will return that number raised to the power of 2